# Modal não abre após usar $('.modal-backdrop').remove()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms, modal

Estou trabalhando com WebForm, utilizando MasterPage.

Minha pagina filha esta dentro do **UpdatePanel**, via c# chamo abertura de um modal dentro de outro modal, só que cada abertura de modal escurece o fundo, e quando mando fechar o modal até que fecha mas somente o modal a cortina escura mantem por de trás e não desaparece.

Para fechar essa cortina utilizo $('.modal-backdrop').remove(), remove a cortina o problema é que não abre mais o modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É provavél que o elemento do modal seja um filho do elemento 'modal-backdrop', desta forma, quando você dá o remove() o elemento e seus filhos são apagados da sua estrutura.

Talvez seja mais interessante você utilizar o .hide()

Answer (score 0):

[Resolvido]

$('.modal-backdrop').remove() -- Mata o html do modal

Resolvi com a estrutura abaixo

Master

Page Filha

```
 <asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true"  ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"  >
   <ContentTemplate>
         --- Modal ---
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<Triggers>                                                              
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnImportarGrade" />
</Triggers>

<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imbDownloadTemplate" />
</Triggers>
```